# MySQL query with left and right join taking 15 minutes to execute

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-performance

We have an old system which displays newsfeed saved on the database. It worked fine before and there were no problem at all. However, now the query does not work and it takes more than 15 minutes to finish the query. For testing i tried out many ways to optimize the query. However, no luck. I would appreciate if any one can give some suggestion. Current database does not have any Index. If anyone think i should create index. please let me know for which tables and what should be the index. I have very little knowledge on indexing. Please find the query that i am running as well the ERD.

```
select *, DATEDIFF(Now(), Date) as Day, DATE_ADD(Date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as Diff from users
left join users_propertyvalues UPV USING(UserId)
left join propertyvalues PV USING(ValueId)
right join item_categories IC ON (IC.CategoryId=UPV.ValueId)
left join newsfeed USING(ItemId)
left join rss_feeds F ON(PV.ValueId=F.FeedId)
where EmailEnabled
having NOW() <= Diff
order by UserId, CategoryId, Date DESC
```

Stack overflow does not allow me to upload the ERD picture. Please let me know if anyone want i can upload it to somewhere.

Thanks for the help.![enter image description here][1]

Comment: `where EmailEnabled` ???

Answer (score 0):

Indexes should be on "joining" columns + add PK for them... aditional You can add `unique` inedexes

ADD PK (it's primary, and UNIQUE):

```
`ALTER TABLE `test`     CHANGE `test` `test` INT(11) NOT NULL,    ADD PRIMARY KEY(`test`);`
```

ADD INDEX (name does no matter):

```
ALTER TABLE `test` ADD UNIQUE `NewIndex1` (`test`);
```

see info http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: Thanks jaczes. Can you give me an example please?

Comment: for example in join `left join users_propertyvalues UPV USING(UserId)` there should be a PK on `users.UserId` and index on `users_propertyvalues.UserId`. And so on for other join-columns. MOreover if You do Have fields with UNIQUE values, You can add such new index - it's better because MYSQL stops searching after first result

Comment: thanks jaczes. what should be the name of the Index? Does it the name matter or it has to be same name as Primary key?

Comment: Jaczes, can you please give me an example of how you would create the index. Just the sql statement. Sorry for asking too much about it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Jaczes, thanks a lot. I was trying to do this "CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UserId
ON `th_users`(UserId)
INCLUDE (EmailEnabled, SmsEnabled)"

Comment: Hi Jaczes, It is not sorted yet. Still having the same problem after indexing. Still it is taking time to execute the query. It took 114s

Comment: 2 min, it's huge progress... i dont have info to help You more. Provide schema and simpple data